# Jquery: Unable to set value of input to table td

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a multi-step form. before the user submits the form I want to show him the data he entered inside a table with JQuery. but I am unable to set the values of the input to the table. I have also checked the console for errors. but there are not any errors showing

How can I solve this?

```js
                 

    var email = $('#email').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var gender = $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    var address = $('#address').val();
    var ethnicity = $('#ethnicity').val();


    if (email) {
        $('#email-val').html(email);
    }
    $('#phone-val').html(phone);
    $('#username-val').html(username);
    $('#address-val').html(address);
    $('#gender-val').html(gender);
    $('#ethnicity-val').html(ethnicity);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="signup-form">
    <div class="form-panel about-user js-active" data-animation="scaleIn">
        <h4>Account Information</h4>
        <div class="mb-4"></div>
        <div class="input-item">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email" class="input-bordered" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-item">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Choose a username" id="username" class="input-bordered" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-item">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Choose a Password" id="password" class="input-bordered" required>
        </div>
        <div class="button-row d-flex mt-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-auto js-btn-next" type="button" title="Next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Email Address:</th>
            <td id="email-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Phone Number:</th>
            <td id="phone-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Username:</th>
            <td id="username-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Address:</th>
            <td id="address-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Ethnicity:</th>
            <td id="ethnicity-val"></td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" style="display:none" id="second">
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is not working? What doesn’t happen? What does happen instead?

Comment: how is defined this `submit` action and how is defined form button for submit?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am unable to set the values of the input to the table.

Comment: add an event listener to your button, and call the method to fill the table

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gnhysqzr/

Comment: @JarlikStepsto consider adding an answer rather than sharing a code link in a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing is that you are not assignin them when push button. You assign them while page is loading and that time it is empty. So you need to assign your click to one function `onclick="Assign()"` and do your process in it

```js
function Assign(){

var email = $('#email').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var gender = $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    var address = $('#address').val();
    var ethnicity = $('#ethnicity').val();


    if (email) {
        $('#email-val').html(email);
    }
    $('#phone-val').html(phone);
    $('#username-val').html(username);
    $('#address-val').html(address);
    $('#gender-val').html(gender);
    $('#ethnicity-val').html(ethnicity);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="signup-form">
    <div class="form-panel about-user js-active" data-animation="scaleIn">
        <h4>Account Information</h4>
        <div class="mb-4"></div>
        <div class="input-item">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email" class="input-bordered" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-item">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Choose a username" id="username" class="input-bordered" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-item">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Choose a Password" id="password" class="input-bordered" required>
        </div>
        <div class="button-row d-flex mt-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-auto js-btn-next"onclick="Assign()" type="button" title="Next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Email Address:</th>
            <td id="email-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Phone Number:</th>
            <td id="phone-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Username:</th>
            <td id="username-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Address:</th>
            <td id="address-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Ethnicity:</th>
            <td id="ethnicity-val"></td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" style="display:none" id="second">
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function fillTable(){
 var email = $('#email').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var gender = $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    var address = $('#address').val();
    var ethnicity = $('#ethnicity').val();


    if (email) {
        $('#email-val').html(email);
    }
    $('#phone-val').html(phone);
    $('#username-val').html(username);
    $('#address-val').html(address);
    $('#gender-val').html(gender);
    $('#ethnicity-val').html(ethnicity);
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="signup-form">
    <div class="form-panel about-user js-active" data-animation="scaleIn">
        <h4>Account Information</h4>
        <div class="mb-4"></div>
        <div class="input-item">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email" class="input-bordered" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-item">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Choose a username" id="username" class="input-bordered" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-item">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Choose a Password" id="password" class="input-bordered" required>
        </div>
        <div class="button-row d-flex mt-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-auto js-btn-next" type="button" title="Next" onclick="fillTable()">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Email Address:</th>
            <td id="email-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Phone Number:</th>
            <td id="phone-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Username:</th>
            <td id="username-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Address:</th>
            <td id="address-val"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Ethnicity:</th>
            <td id="ethnicity-val"></td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" style="display:none" id="second">
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```